# Neural Net Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to figure out the matrix multiplications for the implementation of a single hidden layer neural net for MNIST digit recognition.

Like the following:

```
               h1             
x1                            z1
               h2
x2                            z2
 1             h3

                1
```

I'm using a hidden layer of size 200.

The number of features for the digits is 784.

The number of classes is 10.

Each label is transformed to a vector of length 10 which has a single 1 in the position of the true class and 0 elsewhere.

Between the input and the hidden layer, I'm going to use a 200 by 785 matrix V.

Matrix V: the i, j - entry represents the weight connecting the jth unit in the input layer to the ith unit in the hidden layer. The ith row of V represents the ensemble of weights feeding into the ith hidden unit.

Between the hidden the the output layer, I'm going to apply a matrix W, which is 10 by 201.

Matrix W: the i, j - entry represents the weight connecting the jth unit in the hidden layer to the ith unit in the output layer. The ith row of W is the emsemble of weights feeding into the ith output unit.

So I start with the input matrix, which is n by 784. Can someone explain what to do? What do I need to multiply it by, and then what/how do I multiply the result by? I'm not sure how exactly to multiply these matrices.

(Let's just call the activation functions f().)

I'm a bit confused by the dimensions of the matrices and not sure when /where/ how exactly to use V and W.

Comment: $y_i(t+1) =f( \sum_{j} W_{ij} y_j(t))$ where $W_{ij} y_j(t)$ is the scalar product between the output of the other neurons at time$t$ and the weights to the $i$th neuron. hence you can write the matrix equation $y(t+1) = f(W y(t))$ where $(W y(t))_i = \sum_j W_{ij} y_j(t)$. of course $W$ is a $n \times n $ matrix where $n$ is the number of neurons.

Comment: (I meant where $\sum_j W_{ij} y_j(t)$ is the scalar  product between the ouput of the neurons and the weights to the $i$th neuron)